# SwiftUI: Text mis-alignment when inside Button (bug?)

Tags: swiftui

So this is a weird one, and it looks like a bug. When placed inside a button, title that cannot fit on one line mis-aligns. It should be aligned to the left, but shows up centered.

Everything latest, XCode 13.2.1

MRE is below, any tips much appreciated!

```
HStack {

  HStack{
    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFit()
      .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    Text("Some kind of title") // <- aligned properly
      .fontWeight(.bold)
      .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
  } //: HStack
    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .frame(height: 35)
    .font(.headline)
    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
    .background(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
    .cornerRadius(6)
                
  Button(action: {
    // some action
  }){
    HStack{
      Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
      Text("Some kind of title") // <- not aligned properly
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
    } //: HStack
      .padding(.horizontal, 12)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .frame(height: 35)
      .font(.headline)
      .foregroundColor(Color.green)
      .background(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
      .cornerRadius(6)
  } //: Button

} //: HStack
```

[image: Second row is misaligned]

Comment: Try adding `.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)` to the `Text` view.

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2. Please attach a screenshot of what's wrong.

Comment: Same here, Xcode 13.2.1 / iOS 15.2. Also, make sure you have posted an MRE. There may be some modifier elsewhere in the view that is affecting this.

Comment: I added a screenshot to show what I mean. @tromgy's answer is the right solution, .multilineTextAlignment(.leading) solves it. Thanks! If you post it as an answer I can mark it as solved. Although I still have no idea why it is happening only within Button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding the `multilineTextAlignment` modifier to the `Text` view:

```
Button(action: {
    // some action
  }){
    HStack{
      Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
      Text("Some kind of title")
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading) // <- will align to the left
    } //: HStack
      .padding(.horizontal, 12)
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .frame(height: 35)
      .font(.headline)
      .foregroundColor(Color.green)
      .background(Color.green.opacity(0.2))
      .cornerRadius(6)
  } //: Button
```

As to why it happens, I have a theory. By default `Text` on buttons is centered, while plain `Text` by default is left-aligned. I didn't see it explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but a simple experiment shows this behavior:

[image: Screen shot of Text vs Button]